# second Tab is always greyed out in UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to embed two NavBar Controllers into a UITabbarController, using the code below in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Configure and show the window.

    FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];
    SecondTableViewController *anotherOne = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    self.anotherNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:anotherOne];

    NSArray *twoViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.anotherNav,self.firstNav, nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:twoViewControllers];
    [window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    return YES;
}
```

The two tabs are displayed fine, with their names, but I can select the first one only, the second one is always greyed out and does not respond to touch events. I reversed the navController assignment into the Tabbar (i.e. in the array twoViewControllers), and each view is displayed fine (in the first tab).

The app delegate does not implement UITabbarDelegate and uiTabBarControllerDelegate. I don't use story boards.

Any obvious reason why the second tab is always greyed out ?

Sample Code:
It's just Apple's Locations tutorial (with ARC)
[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008406)

Then change :

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {}

for

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Configure and show the window.

    RootViewController *cont1 = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    RootViewController *cont2 = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (!context) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    cont1.managedObjectContext = context;
    cont2.managedObjectContext = context;

    UINavigationController *aNav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cont1];
    UINavigationController *aNav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cont2];

    NSArray *twoViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:aNav1,aNav2, nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:twoViewControllers];

    //[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

and replace @interface LocationAppDelegate ...@end by

```
@interface LocationsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;

    UITabBarController *tabBarController;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

- (IBAction)saveAction:sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

and Compile and run.

Comment: Does the same problem occur even if you try this NSArray *twoViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.firstNav,self.anotherNav, nil];

Comment: Yes, same problem. The firstNav goes to the first Tab, and is displayed fine, but the second tab can not be selected. It's really this second tab that for some reason doesn't respond to touch events.

Comment: can you forward me the project, as the code seems to be alright.

Comment: Hi Thanks ! I not too sure where to send it since there are no way to send private messages, so I added some more info as to how to replicate this behavior.

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com. you can try it over here, set to and from email to your personal email id. A link will be generated which you can paste it over here

Comment: Hi, thanks, just dropped it here http://www.sendspace.com/file/yewxxn

Comment: @Alex: Do you have solved your problem in the meantime? I have downloaded your project and cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: that's weird, because when I run it on my laptop, the problem is here. Have you changed anything ?

Comment: @Alex: I have only removed the line `[navigationController release]` in `dealloc` of LocationsAppDelegate, because that does not compile. The title "Locations" of the second tab is not visible initially, but I can select the second tab. - I have tested with the iOS 5.1 and iOS 6 Simulator in Xcode 4.5.2.

Comment: @Martin I have no idea why it's working for you and not for me... I took the archive from where I dropped it, and can't select the second tab... May be XCode has a soul ? Or I keep doing the same error without even noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of `[window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];`